# When is the splitting field of a polynomial different from the subfield containing all roots?

Tags: splitting-field

I've seen many times statements like:

Let `K` be the splitting field of P(x) over F, let `G` be the subfield consisting of all the roots of P(x)...

When is `K` different from `G`? IMO the splitting field is already the smallest field so there shouldn't be a proper subfield?

**UPDATE**

one such example can be seen here:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-74725-5_27?noAccess=true

On the proof part of **Theorem 3**, just scroll down a bit and you'll see.

Comment: could you provide a complete example of one of these statements?

Comment: yeah , updated that part.

Comment: Beware: In the text it is written "A splitting field", not "The splitting field". This means $K$ is any field containing all the roots, but it may be bigger

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field Seems the definition of splitting field has already mentioned it's the smallest.

Comment: Books have different definitions.
I just checked in that specific book you linked, and it is not the smallest, but any field $K$ such that $P(x)$ completely factorizes in $K[x]$

Comment: Oops, how is it exactly defined there? I didn't see it. It's rare for math concepts to have conflict definitions.

Comment: https://ibb.co/YfhT5zt

Comment: Seems you're right. Really weird...

Comment: look just before the example. That one is the definition